# where should I save batch files

Tags: batch-file

I've written a a.bat file and I want to use it at command prompt.
for example I've written "d:" in this a.bat file.
Where should I save this file that when I write "a" in command prompt , it goes to drive D ?

Comment: If you're running as an admin it will run from the `System32` folder, else it will run from your user folder.  Which way are you running it?  That will make a difference unless you're writing the whole file path each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to execute the .bat file from the command prompt regardless of the command prompt's current path, then you need to save the .bat file in a directory that is included in the PATH system variable (assuming you are using windows).

For Example

if a.bat is saved in C:\MyDir\MySubDir

`C:\>a.bat` will execute (i.e. the directory will change to D:> if C:\MyDir\MySubDir is in the PATH system variable. If not, you will get a message as follows

`'a.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The PATH variable is populated with a few paths by default, such as C:\Windows\System32. You can also add any path on the system to the PATH variable using the instructions contained in the link below (article is for Windows XP, but its largely the same for Win 7/8 once you get to the system properties).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Answer (score 0):

save it in the current directory and navigate there to execute it without messing with the path if you aren't certain how to do that. if you do use the path, back it up the first few times.